# How hard would it be to set up Conky like this?

Tags: conky

I'm a newbie to the Linux world and I have gotten my Ubuntu  15.04 all set up last night. I was playing around with some features and since I'm a nerd I decided I wanted to change my log in sound to Paarthurnax saying, "Drem Yol Lok, greetings." After that I got the idea that I wanted to somehow customize the desktop to look like [this](http://axerron.deviantart.com/art/Skyrim-Rainmeter-Suite-v2-283817269). Is it possible to replicate this?

[image]

Thanks!

Removed Newbie like me.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a valid question: "how hard would it be for a newbie like me?" All "newbies" aren't the same.

Comment: Isn't that link for Rainmeter or something? If it's a conky config you want to copy, just copy that specific conky config file, probably making a few edits to your taste. Or, you can read the conky help and start editing the conky config file yourself.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes it is for Rainmeter, I was just wondering if in Conky if I could do something similar to this. And if it is possible, how difficult would it be to do. Could I convert a Rainmeter to a conky config file?

Comment: +1. After two years and five months your Ask Ubuntu Rep points have jumped from 1 to 6 :)

Answer (score 1):

Converting from rainmeter config to conky config, maybe if you went through it by hand yourself, but I am not aware of any automatic tool.

Conky can do free drive space, disk read/write speeds, cpu usage, free/total/used ram, sensor temps & fanspeeds, processses, network UL/DL speed & totals... just type them into your config file & test it out.

It's basically just take the default config file, and add/change stuff under the `TEXT` line. And the reload trick `killall -SIGUSR1 conky` is excellent. After you get the right settings above the `TEXT` line to use conky on your desktop, easy web search to find those.

See these pages for more info:

- [Conky Documentation Pages](http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html)

  - [Pretty table of Conky variables](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html)
- [Ubuntu help page on Conky](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky)
- A web search for [best conky configs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=best+conky+configs) - just copy some cool ones & edit away. Could be a lot easier than DIY'ing your own.

Lots of them use LUA and pretty rings and such, but they can take up lots of valuable desktop space... Like this [Hej Conky](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/hej+conky+box?content=149937) setup found on [this page](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/04/top-artworks-on-gnome-look-in-april.html) :

[image: Hej conky image]

I've got a slim bar that crams in almost every stat & graph I might want, and it's small enough to keep it always visible. Could even cover almost all of it up and leave just the 3 or 4 characters on the edge that show most important numbers.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a whirl and see what happens. 

Should I back up Ubuntu? Or is there no chance of ruining my install?

Comment: Conky is just a program that runs on the desktop, it shouldn't change anything...  But it's **always** a good idea to have a backup copy of your important data.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `rainmaker` under `wine` in Linux / Ubuntu. I prefer `conky` docked to the right hand side of my primary monitor with web browser to the left of it:

[image: Conky.gif]